# htaccess redirect for from php with parameters failing

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble with the following redirect.

```
Redirect 302 /info/index.php?product=xxx http://xyz.com/xxx/
```

I don't understand why it's not working.  Do I have to escape a character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `Redirect` directive for matching query string. Use `mod_rewrite` instead.

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://xyz.com/%1/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.